# Layered form don't show

Tags: winforms

I got a problem with my layered form. I made it to show an PNG image with blur in form background. Everything works great in Windows 7 but when i run it at Windows XP my form don't show.

There is my Code:

```
public class LayeredForm : Form
{
    public LayeredForm()
    {
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        Width = 0;
        Height = 0;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    public void SetBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        IntPtr screenDc = Win32Helper.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        IntPtr compatibleMemoryDc = Win32Helper.CreateCompatibleDC(screenDc);
        IntPtr hgdiBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr hgdiOldBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            hgdiBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap(Color.FromArgb(0));
            hgdiOldBitmap = Win32Helper.SelectObject(compatibleMemoryDc, hgdiBitmap);
            Win32Helper.SizeStruct size = new Win32Helper.SizeStruct() 
            { 
                X = bitmap.Width,
                Y = bitmap.Height
            };
            Win32Helper.PointStruct sourcePoint = new Win32Helper.PointStruct();
            Win32Helper.PointStruct topPoint = new Win32Helper.PointStruct() 
            { 
                X = Left,
                Y = Top
            };
            Win32Helper.BlendFunctionStruct blend = new Win32Helper.BlendFunctionStruct()
            {
                BlendOp = 255 /* opacity */,
                BlendFlags = 0x00 /* AC_SRC_OVER */,
                AlphaFormat = 0x01 /* AC_SRC_ALPHA */,
                SourceConstantAlpha = byte.MaxValue
            };
            Win32Helper.UpdateLayeredWindow(this.Handle, screenDc, ref topPoint, ref size, compatibleMemoryDc,
                ref sourcePoint, 0, ref blend, 2 /* ULW_ALPHA */);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (screenDc != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Win32Helper.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, screenDc);
            }
            if (hgdiBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Win32Helper.SelectObject(compatibleMemoryDc, hgdiOldBitmap);
                Win32Helper.DeleteObject(hgdiBitmap);
            }
            Win32Helper.DeleteDC(compatibleMemoryDc);
        }
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x00080000;  // Turn on WS_EX_LAYERED
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

I use it in my other form by extend and set my image with SetBitmap() function. My form is empty border less form and this is not a child window (the WS_EX_LAYERED does not work for a child window for older windows than Windows 8).

Comment: Calling winapi functions requires explicit error checking, you don't have the friendly .NET Framework anymore to throw exceptions for you.  You have no error checking whatsoever.  So of course you can't know why it doesn't work either.  Do *not* ignore the function return value.